# setEnterTransition not working

Tags: android, android-transitions

My Transition is not working and i don't know what i'm missing or doing wrong.
I want to implement an EnterTransition, the Detail Activity launches a Fragment.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Intent intent=getIntent();

            Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
            Integer integer=(Integer)bundle.get("movieId");
            bundle.putString("movieId",String.valueOf(integer));
            DetailActivityFragment detailActivityFragment=new DetailActivityFragment();
            detailActivityFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                addEnterTransitionV21(detailActivityFragment);
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.detail_activity_container,detailActivityFragment)
                  //  .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }



 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void addEnterTransitionV21(Fragment fragment) {
        Slide slideTransition = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
        slideTransition.addTarget(R.id.content_transition);
        slideTransition.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this,
                android.R.interpolator.linear_out_slow_in));
        slideTransition.setDuration(1000);
        fragment.setEnterTransition(slideTransition);

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.